# TYPO3 view page content

Tags: php, web, typo3, content-management-system

I created some elements in page named as "Home"
[image: elements in "home" page]

but when I click "view" or want to see preview I get "hello world"

[image: viem]

I now that for view I need create template and setup it

[image: Setup]

but I don't understand what I need to write to see the elements that I created.
I would like to receive step by step instructions.

Comment: First you need to start from original documentation: https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/tutorial-templating/master/en-us/MinimalDesign/Index.html Your question doesn't fit Stackoverflow's requirements, therefore will be closed.

Comment: @biesior Please give more specific reasons in order for the poster to be able to improve the question.

Comment: @JonasEberle that's already described in: ['How to ask' article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)... since years. Showing us screenshots with **hello world** TS is not a question, it's a mockery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Boostrap including]
problem solved. in page template setup just need to include boostrap package

Answer (score 0):

As a starter, you can add this in TypoScript setup to see your content:

```
page.100 < styles.content.get
```

In a default installation, that is a predefined TypoScript object which looks like this:

```
page.100 = CONTENT
page.100 {
    table = tt_content
    select {
        orderBy = sorting
        where = {#colPos}=0
    }
}
```

This renders content from your first column (`colPos=0`) (`Normal` in your case).

This will just render the content - without any layout around it. So it's not useful for anything else than testing or learning the basic content rendering. It will get used for building a layout, though:

This is a simple but conceptually slightly outdated (but still helpful) tutorial to learn about templating: https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/tutorial-templating/10.4/en-us/Index.html

If you are planning to get deeper into TYPO3 I recommend to create a sitepackage by following this tutorial: https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/tutorial-sitepackage/10.4/en-us/Index.html - that is the recommended base for your TYPO3 implementation.